# Output an array value as parameter

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$title = array("'ID', 'Nick', 'Name'", "'ID', 'Nick', 'Count'");
```

And I want to execute this: (setHeaders is from Console_Table package)

```
$tbl->setHeaders(array($title[0]));
```

But instead of:

```
$tbl->setHeaders(array('ID', 'Nick', 'Name'));
```

I'm getting outputs like I would run this:

```
$tbl->setHeaders(array("'ID', 'Nick', 'Name'"));
```

How can I do it? Thank you for help

Comment: Your array only has 1 element. You want to split your element into multiple ones.

Comment: `$tbl->setHeaders(array(explode(", ", $title[0])));`

Comment: Are you assigning `$array` yourself or is it coming from somewhere? It only has 2 elements of two strings.

Comment: What you probably want to do is something like this: `$title = str_getcsv($title[0], ",", "'");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a multidimensional array:

```
$title = array(array('ID', 'Nick', 'Name'),
               array('ID', 'Nick', 'Count');

$tbl->setHeaders($title[0]);
```

Will pass an array:

```
$tbl->setHeaders(array('ID', 'Nick', 'Name'));
```

Comment: Assuming he is manually constructing this, this answer works. Exploding the string is another option that will also work in case he's given these arrays like this.

Comment: That array is indeed manually constructed (sorry for not including this information), and this answer works for me perfectly. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is a little... incorrectly built. You're going to want to split the string. Assuming this is PHP:

```
function explodeTitleString($string){
    return array explode(',', $string);
}
$title = array array_map(explodeTitleString, $title);
// continue on
```

Comment: You'll need to use `str_getcsv` to get rid of the single quotes.